# EXEC : error GQL: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: JSON

Tags: c#, graphql

I am [**following this strawberry shake tutorial**](https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/v13/get-started/console) in C# console app. All the steps are successfully performed but when I tried to build using `dotnet build` , it is getting failed with the below error:

EXEC : error GQL: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: JSON [D:\HTH\GraphQL\StrawberryShake_Graphql_client\GraphqlStrawberry\GraphqlStrawberry\GraphqlStrawberry.csproj]
C:\Users\Faizan Khan.nuget\packages\strawberryshake.server\13.0.5\build\StrawberryShake.Server.targets(63,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "C:\Users\Faizan Khan.nuget\packages\strawberry
shake.server\13.0.5\build..\tools\net6\dotnet-graphql.dll" generate "D:\HTH\GraphQL\StrawberryShake_Graphql_client\GraphqlStrawberry\GraphqlStrawberry" -o "D:\HTH\GraphQL\StrawberryShake_Graphq
l_client\GraphqlStrawberry\GraphqlStrawberry\obj\Debug\net6.0\berry" -n GraphqlStrawberry -a md5 -t" exited with code 1. [D:\HTH\GraphQL\StrawberryShake_Graphql_client\GraphqlStrawberry\GraphqlS
trawberry\GraphqlStrawberry.csproj]

Build FAILED.

EXEC : error GQL: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: JSON [D:\HTH\GraphQL\StrawberryShake_Graphql_client\GraphqlStrawberry\GraphqlStrawberry\GraphqlStrawberry.csproj]
C:\Users\Faizan Khan.nuget\packages\strawberryshake.server\13.0.5\build\StrawberryShake.Server.targets(63,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "C:\Users\Faizan Khan.nuget\packages\strawberry
shake.server\13.0.5\build..\tools\net6\dotnet-graphql.dll" generate "D:\HTH\GraphQL\StrawberryShake_Graphql_client\GraphqlStrawberry\GraphqlStrawberry" -o "D:\HTH\GraphQL\StrawberryShake_Graphq
l_client\GraphqlStrawberry\GraphqlStrawberry\obj\Debug\net6.0\berry" -n GraphqlStrawberry -a md5 -t" exited with code 1. [D:\HTH\GraphQL\StrawberryShake_Graphql_client\GraphqlStrawberry\GraphqlS
trawberry\GraphqlStrawberry.csproj]
0 Warning(s)
2 Error(s)

Here are the steps which i have taken before building the project

1. create console project .net 6
2. then i open terminal put dotnet new tool-manifest
3. dotnet add Demo package StrawberryShake.Server
4. dotnet graphql init https://web.com/graphql/ -n ConferenceClient -p ./Demo
5. Added namespace in json file
6. Make a query
7. dotnet build command and got above error.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue after updating things to V13. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: not yet if you found a solution then post here please

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is related to the .graphqlrc.json configuration file being too open (due to the "any directory" value) once the generated files are created.

What worked for me was to create a sub-directory and place all of the source query files in there.

To give a specific example, I added a "[project root]/client_queries" directory and moved all of the *.graphql query files into this directory.

I then changed the following value for the "documents" element in the .graphqlrc.json configuration file from:

```
{
  "schema": "schema.graphql",
  "documents": "**\*.graphql",  <-- CHANGED THIS
  "extensions": {
    "strawberryShake": {
      "name": "StrawberryClient",
      "url": "https://example.com/graphql"
    }
  }
}
```

to the specific directory that holds the source query files:

```
{
  "schema": "schema.graphql",
  "documents": "client_queries\*.graphql", <-- TO THIS
  "extensions": {
    "strawberryShake": {
      "name": "StrawberryClient",
      "url": "https://example.com/graphql"
    }
  }
}
```

I rebuilt the solution and this appears to have resolved the referenced error for me. Hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That issue might be caused also by the bug in StrawberryShake client generation process. The process is failed with exact the same message when the schema contains 'scalar JSON'. [Here](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/issues/6257#issuecomment-1597595588) are the details and the workaround described.